# coustomizin ubuntu 23.10

Tags: chroot, isolinux

I am currently in the process of creating a custom Ubuntu 23.10 ISO with a specific aim to initiate a minimal desktop environment along with a designated startup application when booted from a USB drive. However, I've encountered challenges regarding the size of the resulting ISO, which exceeds my requirements.

My primary goal is to optimize this customized ISO to the smallest possible size while ensuring it still boots into the desired desktop environment with the designated startup application and no additional packages or components.

Could you kindly provide guidance or best practices to help reduce the ISO size while maintaining the essential functionality of the customized image? Specifically, I aim to remove unnecessary packages and installing packages from chroot edit(folder) , configure the boot process for a lightweight environment, automate the startup of the essential application, and possibly utilize compression methods to achieve this size reduction.

Your insights or suggestions on minimizing the ISO size without compromising functionality would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read and experimented with the basic resources on the topic, at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization ?

Comment: yes I follwed the same. But there are lots of changes in snaps after update. And packages get auto-installed even after removing while in chroot.